# Important Scala concepts to "be thorough in" when learning Lift

Tags: scala, lift

I am learning Scala with the intention that I be able to develop in Lift. What are the Scala concepts that are **highly ingrained** to Lift, that I must be thorough in?

What are the concepts/design styles that I must start early to lead to **maintainable** Lift projects?

Particularly, I am interested in lazy vars, actors and pattern matching

Comment: i don't know lift so can't answer your specific question, but if you are playing with scala, you may want to read through 'programming in scala' book. There are quite a few concepts that you would most probably use anyways, irrespective of the framework.

Comment: There are probably several Non-Scala concepts that you need to be aware of too.. For instance Javascript, AJAX, HTML, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, there are no scala fields that you won't use in Lift. Of course it can depend a lot on what you are working on. For exemple I did't have to use actors but some people chose Scala for their webapp because of them.

However here is what I personally recommend as a first aid kit:

- **The List API**

I use a lot the `List` [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html). Mastering it is useful for all data anylisis and filtering cases. If you use `Mapper[T]` in Lift, it will return some `List[T]` as a result.

As you are interested in pattern matching I am sorry to tell you that with `List` you won't have to use `match` a lot.

- **Object oriented programming**

It sounds silly but another interesting fields to master is the difference between `Class` and `Object` including of course inner classes and inner objects as, later on in Lift they will have different meanings in snippets to know if the snippet is a singleton, if the `val` is static of not...

Scala traits can also be powerful in `Lift` context, but in fact they are useful everywhere

- **Scala XML support**

Mastering Scala XML will be very useful as you will certainly have to set some xml by hand, so if you don't have problems with this it will be really helpful.

Comment: Please comment on actors too. What features implement the interactive comet and "wiring"?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I don't know them enough, even if I used WiringUI in my code. It can be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

To the list Chris wrote I would add:

- **Actors**

While Lift has it own LiftActor and CometActors implementation, it is helpful to understand how to interact and use the actor paradigm. Comet, which is one of the best features in Lift is written using Actors.

- **Box**

Lift has something similar to Scala's Option, called Box. A box can have any of these three statues, Full, Empty or Failure. You can read more about it on David's [blog](http://lift.la/scala-option-lift-box-and-how-to-make-your-co)

- **Where to find help**

While you will find useful answers here on SO (Like Chris's answer), most of the Lift community hangs out at the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb). There are thousands of questions and answers there.

We are currently working on a [cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/), there is the 
[wiki](http://assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/), there are three books about Lift, [Lift in Action](http://www.manning.com/perrett/), [SImply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/) and [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net/)